# compare two dataset and create a new dataframe by looking at the union of both dataset

Tags: r

I have two dataframe df1 and df2, i want to create a new dataframe by looking at the union of the two dataset. If a particular column has value 1 in both dataset, the new dataset should have value 1 for that particular column.

```
    df1 = data.frame( V1 = letters[1:5], V2 = c("0","1","1","0","1"), V3 = c("0","0","0","0","1"), V4 =c("1","1","1","1","1"), V5 = c("0","0","0","0","1"),V6 =c("1","1","1","0","0"))

    df2 = data.frame( V1 = letters[1:5], V2 = c("1","1","1","0","0"), V3 = c("1","0","0","0","1"), V4 =c("0","0","1","0","1"), V5 = c("1","0","0","0","1"))

   result = data.frame( V1 = letters[1:5], V2 = c("1","1","1","0","1"), V3 = c("1","0","0","0","1"), V4 =c("1","1","1","1","1"), V5 = c("1","0","0","0","1"),V6 =c("1","1","1","0","0"))
```

Comment: Did you create the zeros and ones in V2--V6 as strings on purpose? Can those be numbers?

Comment: it has to be numbers , my mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my first attempt; although I'm sure this can be improved:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(345)

df1 <- tibble(
  V1 = letters[1:5],
  V2 = sample(c(0,1), 5, replace = TRUE),
  V3 = sample(c(0,1), 5, replace = TRUE)
)

df2 <- tibble(
  V1 = letters[1:5],
  V2 = sample(c(0,1), 5, replace = TRUE),
  V3 = sample(c(0,1), 5, replace = TRUE)
)

df1

# A tibble: 5 x 3
     V1    V2    V3
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1     a     0     1
2     b     0     0
3     c     0     1
4     d     1     0
5     e     0     0

df2

# A tibble: 5 x 3
     V1    V2    V3
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1     a     0     0
2     b     1     1
3     c     0     0
4     d     1     1
5     e     1     1
```

The draft solution:

```
result <- df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = "V1") %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    V2 = max(V2.x, V2.y),
    V3 = max(V3.x, V3.y)
  ) %>% 
  select(V1, V2, V3)

result

# A tibble: 5 x 3
     V1    V2    V3
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1     a     0     1
2     b     1     1
3     c     0     1
4     d     1     1
5     e     1     1
```

Obviously, if you have a large number of variables, this becomes a less ideal answer.

**UPDATE:**

Here is how to make the solution even more general for an arbitrary number of columns:

```
df1 %>% 
  select(V1) %>% 
  bind_cols( 
    map2_df(
      .x = df1[-1],
      .y = df2[-1], 
      .f = ~ map2_dbl(.x, .y, max)
    )
  )
# A tibble: 5 x 3
     V1    V2    V3
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1     a     0     1
2     b     1     1
3     c     0     1
4     d     1     1
5     e     1     1
```

**This is how it works:**

We can supply map2_dbl with one pair of vectors and find the max of the two vectors at each position like so:

```
map2_dbl(
  .x = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0), 
  .y = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1), 
  .f = max
)

[1] 0 1 0 1 1
```

That will become the inner-most portion of the solution. Now, we just need to figure out how to pass in all pairs of variables from both data frames iteratively to the map2_dbl above. This silly example shows how it works:

```
map2(
  .x = df1[-1], 
  .y = df2[-1], 
  .f = function(x = .x, y = .y) {
    cat("x = ", x, "y = ", y, "\n")
  }
)

x =  0 0 0 1 0 y =  0 1 0 1 1 
x =  1 0 1 0 0 y =  0 1 0 1 1 
$V2
NULL

$V3
NULL
```

Notice that in the first pass x = df1$V2 and y = df2$V2. In the second iteration x = df1$V3 and y = df2$V3. That is exactly what we want.

We could use three steps to get our final solution:

```
x1 <- df1 %>% 
  select(V1)

x2 <- map2_df(
  .x = df1[-1], 
  .y = df2[-1], 
  .f = function(x = .x, y = .y) {
    map2_dbl(x, y, max)
  }
)

bind_cols(x1, x2)

# A tibble: 5 x 3
     V1    V2    V3
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1     a     0     1
2     b     1     1
3     c     0     1
4     d     1     1
5     e     1     1
```

OR, we can combine these steps into one pipeline:

```
df1 %>% 
  select(V1) %>% 
  bind_cols( 
    map2_df(
      .x = df1[-1],
      .y = df2[-1], 
      .f = ~ map2_dbl(.x, .y, max)
    )
  )
# A tibble: 5 x 3
     V1    V2    V3
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1     a     0     1
2     b     1     1
3     c     0     1
4     d     1     1
5     e     1     1
```

Comment: for my example this works well, but my dataset id dim(df1) : 21677   125

Comment: very well explained. What if the df1 and df2 have different number of rows?

Comment: I’m pretty sure map2 requires the .x and .y arguments to be the same length. One option would be to append rows that just contain “NA” to the shorter data frame. Not sure if that’s a “good” option or not.